# Command Line Python versus Anaconda

Tags: python, import, command-line

I'm trying to utilize the command line in Windows for Python as much as possible, and obviously have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to enter commands.

1. Windows Key + R
2. Type "CMD"
3. Type "python" at C:\Users\Owner prompt
4. Type "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"

ERROR MESSAGE:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", kube 1m ub 
ModuleNotFound: No module named 'matplotlib'

Comment: hmmm have you tried `pip install matplotlib`? https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.  Your suggestion worked at the 'C:\Users\Owner' prompt.  I was under the impression that I had to be in Python, i.e., (1) Enter "Python" at the' C:\Users\Owner' prompt, and then, (2) Enter 'pip install matplotlib'.

While I use Anaconda and the Spyder IDE, I'm curious if there is a non-Anaconda Python, for which, I have duplicate packages.  I will explore that next.

Answer (score 0):

you should first activate the environment that has `matplotlib`. For example, you installed it at the default environment of anaconda which is `base`. Then do the following:

1. type `python`
2. type `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: At which particular prompt-level are these commands to be entered?  For example the C:\Users\Owner?  The reason I asked:  When I typed "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt AFTER I typed "python" at the C:\Users\Owner prompt, the import attempt gave me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Before your commands type

```
activate root
```

so all your commands with responses will look like

```
C:\> activate root
(base) C:\> python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>>
```